# Any SQL autocomplete tool for string-SQL parameter?

Tags: java, sql, autocomplete, intellij-idea, intellisense

On the first place, I apologize if the title is confusing because I did not know how to name it other way.

Basically, what I need is a tool which could help me complete SQL code when I pass it as a parameter (string parameter). For example

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME); //intellisense does not work here
```

In case of long SQL commands passed as a parameter, it's very time consuming to watch not to make mistakes in SQL code (which I do after hours of coding).

Any good tool to help me?

The language is Java and the IDE is IntelliJ IDEA, but I am open to any external light-weight tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEA already [supports it](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/sql_java.html), make sure [data source](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/data-sources.html) is configured and [language injection](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/language-injection.html) is enabled:
[image]

Comment: Is this generic for every project or I have to create it for every new project?

Comment: When you define new data source, you have a choice for its level: Project or Global: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/jdbc-data-source-properties.html